# Monitor glitches in 18.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I know there are some questions about the monitor problems in the site but none of those that I've found was able to help me. Here is the situation:

I have an intel desktop PC with an `GeForce GTX 1050 Ti` and NVIDIA driver version `390.116`. Attach to it there are two identical monitors one of which problematic. The one *without* any issue is connected via a DVI cable. As for the problematic, it was connected with display port when it started to glitch (genuinely for the lack of better words, just like sci-fi movies when the hacker take over). So it would start to glitch 5~10 minutes after start up and couple of minutes after glitching it would black out.

This is my work PC so I have access to lots of hardware. This is what I did:

- I changed the display port cable, then
- I changed the monitor with an identical one, then
- I switched to HDMI, then
- I switched the graphics card to an identical one (and tried all the above)

Not a single one these solved my problem. The computer has a integrated gpu as well. So I connected the glitchy display to onboard HDMI and the okay monitor to NVIDIA via DVI as before. The glitch still occurs, however, now the monitor doesn't go black. Also the glitches are lesser in their intensity but occurring none the less.

All the above tells me this is a software issue. But here is the thing: I used this machine for a year and I do manual upgrades. I have not upgraded the system since its first installation. So basically this problem came out of nowhere. I did upgrade after going through all those bullet points mentioned above but the problem still exists.

Any thoughts?

---

Some further info: 
Graphic card temperature was always at around 31~35 degrees. PowerMizer setting both on adaptive and performance. No heavy load, just simple coding.